# How do you show the time on both monitors?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to do something to get GNOME to show the current time on both of my monitors in GNOME 42. I'm referring to the date and time widget in the centre of the top bar:

[image]

I previously used the Multi-Monitors Add-On, but upgrading to 22.04 LTS broke this since it does not support GNOME 42.

I see [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) gives the effect I want, but has the side effect of, well, merging the dash with the panel.